# Error Dividing Vectors Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made a class vector but it doesn't divide correctly when I want to divide Vector / 0, it doesn't throw an error:

```
class Vector(tuple):

    '''"Class to calculate the usual operations with vectors in bi and
    tridimensional coordinates. Too with n-dimmensinal.'''
    # __slots__=('V') #It's not possible because V is a variable list of param.
    def __new__(cls, *V):
        '''The new method, we initialize the coordinates of a vector.
        You can initialize a vector for example: V = Vector() or
        V = Vector(a,b) or V = Vector(v1, v2, ..., vn)'''
        if not V:
            V = (0, 0)
        elif len(V) == 1:
            raise ValueError('A vector must have at least 2 coordinates.')
        return tuple.__new__(cls, V)

   def __mul__(self, V):
    '''The operator mult overloaded. You can multipy 2 vectors coordinate
     by coordinate.'''
    if type(V) == type(self):
        if len(self) != len(V):
            raise IndexError('Vectors must have same dimmensions')
        else:
            multiplied = tuple(a * b for a, b in zip(self, V))
    elif isinstance(V, type(1)) or isinstance(V, type(1.0)):
        multiplied = tuple(a * V for a in self)
    return Vector(*multiplied)

__rmul__ = __mul__

   def make_one(self, long):
        one = tuple(1 for a in range(0, long))
        return Vector(*one)

    def __truediv__(self, V):
        if type(V) == type(self):
            if len(self) != len(V):
                raise IndexError('Vectors must have same dimmensions.')
            if 0 in V:
                raise ZeroDivisionError('Division by 0.')
            divided = tuple(a / b for a, b in zip(self, V))
            return Vector(*divided)
        elif isinstance(V, int) or isinstance(V, float):
            if V == 0:
                return self * V * Vector().make_one(len(self))
                #raise ZeroDivisionError('Division by 0.')
            return self * (1 / V) * Vector().make_one(len(self))

    __rtruediv__ = __truediv__
```

The test code:

```
from Vector import Vector

def main():
    V1 = Vector(3, 2, -1, 5)

    print(0 / V1)
    print(V1 / 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The console output

(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 0)

The first output is right, but the second one is wrong, the right way would be ErrorDivision by 0.

Comment: ...you've commented out the error raise

Comment: `__rmul__ = __mul__` and `__rtruediv__ = __truediv__` are not correct implementations of `__rmul__` and `__rtruediv__`. The interaction of this bug and the bug jonrsharpe mentions causes `0 / V` to look right, when in fact the code is doubly wrong.

Comment: Tuples are immutable types in Python, so make sure to document that your Vector behaves differently. I can also really recommend using [`numpy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/index.html) since you probably want to do more complicated computations in future.

Answer (score 0):

ok, thanks to @user2357112 the right code is this:

```
def __truediv__(self, V):
    if type(V) == type(self):
        if len(self) != len(V):
            raise IndexError('Vectors must have same dimmensions.')
        if 0 in V:
            raise ZeroDivisionError('Division by 0.')
        divided = tuple(a / b for a, b in zip(self, V))
        return Vector(*divided)
    elif isinstance(V, int) or isinstance(V, float):
        if V == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError('Division by 0.')
        return self * (1 / V) * Vector().make_one(len(self))

#__rtruediv__ = __truediv__
def __rtruediv__(self, V):
    if isinstance(V, int) or isinstance(V, float):
        if V == 0:
            return self * V * Vector().make_one(len(self))
        return self * (1 / V) * Vector().make_one(len(self))
```

Comment: I don't see what the point of multiplying by `Vector().make_one(len(self))` is in your code. Don't you get the same result if you skip that entirely? Also, a good idea is to put `else: return NotImplemented` at the end of your operators, if they don't already handle all possible input types (otherwise you may get `None` unexpectedly).